# fft(x) different from fft(ifft(fft(x))?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, ifft

I normalized the spectrum of a time series and windowed the spectrum, then something strange happened. The code below can run in MATLAB or Octave.

```
figure;
n = 2e3;
t = 1:n;
m = n/2+1;
f = linspace(0,1,m);
x = rand(1,n) - 0.5;
y = fft(x);
subplot(2,2,1); plot(t,x,'k'); 
axis tight; xlabel('t/s'); title('original signal x');
subplot(2,2,2); plot(f,abs(y(1:m)),'k'); 
axis tight; xlabel('f/hz'); title('original spectrum');
y1 = y ./ abs(y);  
k = n/10;
w = sin(linspace(0,pi/2,k));
y1(1:k) = y1(1:k) .* w;
y1(m:-1:m-k+1) = y1(m:-1:m-k+1) .* w;
y1(n-m+3:n) = y1(m-1:-1:2);  
x1 = real(ifft(y1));
y2 = fft(x1);
x2 = real(ifft(y2));
subplot(2,2,3); plot(t,x1,'k',t,x2-x1,'r'); 
axis tight; xlabel('t/s'); title('whitened signal x1(black) and x2-x1(red)');
subplot(2,2,4); plot(f,abs(y1(1:m)),'k',f,abs(y2(1:m)),'r');
axis tight; xlabel('f/hz'); title('whitened spectrum y1(black) and y2(red)');
```

As shown in subplot 3, the red line is the difference between `x1` and `x2`, meaning that they are exactly the same, but as shown in subplot 4, their spectrum (black and red, respectively) is different. 
So, It's weird FFT of IFFT of a spectrum is different from the spectrum itself.

[image: figure1]

Comment: Check your gains in `fft()` and `ifft()`. If I remember correctly, running through a `fft()`/`ifft()` round trip in MATLAB gives you a net gain of `N`, the FFT size.

Comment: I'm confused.  You're windowing the spectrum?  But you expect it to be unwindowed when inverse transformed?

Comment: @endolith: I agree that what he's trying to do is not very clear, but if you trace through the above code, you effectively have at one point `y2 = fft(real(ifft(y1));`, so he expects `y1 == y2`, which is the crux of his question from my reading of it.

Comment: @JasonR: Why does it need real()?  Is the windowing of the spectrum not correctly symmetrical, which produces small imaginary parts, which when removed cause y1 != y2?

Comment: @endolith, JasonR got what I meant. I had a test and found that without real(), x1 and x2 are complex.

Comment: `ifft(fft(x))` is real, isn't it?

Comment: @JasonR, yes, u r correct. I normalized the spectrum to make it flat (spectrum whitening), but I don't want the low and high frequencies. I'm confused that in subplot 4, the red curve is expected to be the same as the black curve.

Comment: @endolith, yes, it is real and equals to x (the error is at the order of eps, 10^-16). I saw that without real(), y1 and y2 are consistent.

Comment: Yeah, so your windowing in the frequency domain is causing it.  Remember that the frequencies of the FFT are like [0, +1, +2, -3, -2, -1].  The -1 frequency bin should be affected the same way that the +1 frequency bin is.  It's "off by one symmetrical".  Maybe changing it to `y1(2:k+1) = y1(2:k+1) .* w;` is enough?

Comment: @endolith, I found the bug. Changing "y1(n-m+3:n) = y1(m-1:-1:2);" to "y1(n-m+3:n) = conj(y1(m-1:-1:2));" fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hilmar was right, its a problem with the FFT indexing. Actually, you took care of the DC which does not appear in the right-side copy of FFT. Like-wise you've to take care of Fs/2 component.

Here is the modified working code.

```
figure;
n = 2e3;
t = 1:n;
m = n/2+1;
f = linspace(0,1,m);
x = rand(1,n) - 0.5;
y = fft(x);
subplot(2,2,1); plot(t,x,'k'); 
axis tight; xlabel('t/s'); title('original signal x');
subplot(2,2,2); plot(f,abs(y(1:m)),'k'); 
axis tight; xlabel('f/hz'); title('original spectrum');
y1 = y ./ abs(y);  
k = n/10;
w = sin(linspace(0,pi/2,k));
y1(1:k) = y1(1:k) .* w;
y1(m-k:m-2) = y1(m-k:m-2).*fliplr(w(2:end));
y1(m-1:m+k-2) = y1(m-1:m+k-2).*w;
y1(n-k+2:n) = y1(n-k+2:n).*fliplr(w(2:end));

x1 = real(ifft(y1));
y2 = fft(x1);
x2 = real(ifft(y2));
subplot(2,2,3); plot(t,x1,'k',t,x2-x1,'r'); 
axis tight; xlabel('t/s'); title('whitened signal x1(black) and x2-x1(red)');
subplot(2,2,4); plot(f,abs(y1(1:m)),'k',f,abs(y2(1:m)),'r');
axis tight; xlabel('f/hz'); title('whitened spectrum y1(black) and y2(red)');
```

The resulting figures are:
[image]

Comment: bingo. perfect.

Comment: Whether or not should I taper the ends of x before fft?

Comment: Why would you need to do it? How do you think it will benefit you?

Comment: in fact, I didn't do the tapering. but other people told me it's better to taper the two ends and he didn't tell me why.

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be that your windowing function doesn't preserve complex conjugate symmetry. So ifft(y1) has a significant imaginary part. By discarding this through the real() operation you induce a significant error which results in the discrepancy. To verify try

```
z = ifft(y1); plot(imag(z));
```

Comment: y r correct. I was wrong. y1 was symmetrical but not conjugate.